# WPF MVVM binding works from ViewModel to XAML, but not in reverse. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, viewmodel

So here's my XAML:

```
    <TextBox Name="FirstNameTextBox"
             Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=FirstName}" 
             Style="{StaticResource StandardTextBoxTheme}"
             Width="180"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Margin="0 0 0 10" />
    <Button Name="CreatePersoenlicheUntersuchungButton"
            Content="Unterlagen erstellen"
            Style="{StaticResource StandardButtonTheme}"
            Command="{Binding CreateMedicalExaminationCommand}" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
```

And here's my ViewModel:

```
public class MedicalExaminationViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private IGlobalConfig _globalConfig;
    private ILogger _logger;
    private IDataAccess _dataAccess;

    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(this, () => FirstName);
        }
    }

    private string _lastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set
        {
            _lastName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(this, () => LastName);
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ICommand CreateMedicalExaminationCommand { get; set; }

    public MedicalExaminationViewModel(ILogger logger, IDataAccess dataAccess, IGlobalConfig globalConfig)
    {
        _globalConfig = globalConfig;
        _logger = logger;
        _dataAccess = dataAccess;

        CreateMedicalExaminationCommand =
           new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(CreateMedicalExaminationAsync));
    }
    // This method gets called when pressing the Button and the Text in the Textboxes gets updated after setting the Properties here.
    public async void CreateMedicalExaminationAsync(object obj)
    {            
        FirstName = "Test_FirstName";
        LastName = "Test_LastName";

        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(FirstName);
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(LastName);
    }

    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged<T>(object source, Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
    {
        string propertyName = GetPropertyName(source, propertyExpression);
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(source, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
  
    public string GetPropertyName<T>(object source, Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
    {
        var memberExpression = propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
        var propertyName = memberExpression.Member.Name;

        return propertyName;
    }
}
```

When I fill in the TextBox and press the button, CreateMedicalExaminationAsync() gets called as it should. However the FirstName Property is empty. When I set the FirstName Property in my ViewModel, it gets updated in the View as it should. How can I get the TextBox.Text into my Property in the ViewModel? Thanks in advance!

Edit: Removing the Style as Yarik mentioned made it work instantly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try adding UpdateSourceTrigger:
`Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`

Comment: Does it work if you remove `Style="{StaticResource StandardTextBoxTheme}"`? If yes, there's something with the style.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow! Please remember to not add too much code to your questions - try and isolate the parts that are causing the issues, and only include the necessary code. Also, [Snoop](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf) is a lifesaver when working with WPF, to inspect your bindings during run-time. This tool often helped me when some binding was not working as expected, because it had a wrong data context.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback, will definitely take it into account in the future! I will also take a look at Snoop!

Answer (score -1):

Removing the Style as [Yarik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/693933/yarik) mentioned [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68119112/wpf-mvvm-binding-works-from-viewmodel-to-xaml-but-not-in-reverse-what-am-i-doi/68119400#comment120395740_68119112)

> Does it work if you remove `Style="{StaticResource StandardTextBoxTheme}"`? If yes, there's something with the style.

made it work instantly.

Turns out the control template I defined in the static resource was overriding the text property in the view file. The property itself was fine as it is.